# Are the one-to-many and many-to-one tags needed?

Tags: discussion, tags

I saw both of these tags on a question ([Infinite recursion with JPA relationship (OneToMany and ManyToOne)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330302/infinite-recursion-with-jpa-relationship-onetomany-and-manytoone)) and it has me wondering if they are really needed or not? I've always thought tags were a supposed to be broader "topics" (for lack of a better word) that people are interested in rather than a very specific concept. Having these as tags really doesn't make sense in my mind. I've included all the tag information below:

---

[many-to-one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/many-to-one)

**Description:**

> Defines a single-valued association to another entity class that has many-to-one multiplicity. It is not normally necessary to specify the target entity explicitly since it can usually be inferred from the type of the object being referenced. If the relationship is bidirectional, the non-owning OneToMany entity side must used the mappedBy element to specify the relationship field or property of the entity that is the owner of the relationship.

**Followers:** 0

**Questions:** 399

---

[one-to-many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/one-to-many)

**Description:**

> one-to-many is relationship between two different object properties.

**Followers:** 4,

**Questions:** 1.5 K

---

I realize that each tag has a semi-decent amount of questions associated with it. The tags themselves though really don't seem to add anything of value to the question. The *one-to-many* description is very weak and they seem too specific of concepts for the broader tagging spectrum. I personally believe tagging the question with the database tag your using such as [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) or [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) would be a lot more effective. With only 4 followers between the two tags, they are obviously not traffic drivers in terms of getting views. So I'm wondering should these tags be removed?

I may be really off base with my judgement on this question. This may ignite a firestorm of followers to go add these tags to their favorites list for all I know. Just interested to hear some community feedback.

Comment: Clean-up is required, but not burination. These tags are required for relationships.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion wouldn't tagging the question with the database tag your using be sufficient? The tags are for guidance if I'm understanding them correctly.

Comment: Inclined to agree with you @War10ck ...I see these tags from time to time on questions with the SQL tag, and they are usually quite redundant (kinda like the table tag)